# Truncated distribution $f(x;\theta)=\theta x^{-(\theta-1)}$

Tags: distributions, truncation

I'm trying to derive for p.m.f.

$$f(x;\theta)=\theta x^{-(\theta-1)}$$

$x>1, \theta > 0$

the truncated distribution that excludes observations $1<X≤a$
$$f(x | X > a)=\frac{g(x)}{1-F(a)}$$

where

$$g(x)=f(x) \text{, for } x>a, 0 \text{ otherwise}$$

I'm getting

$$f(x | X > a)=\frac{\theta x^{-(\theta-1)}}{1-F(a)}$$

But what is $F(a)$?

Is $F(a)=\int_0^a f(x;\theta)dx$?
Or perhaps $F(a)=\int_1^a f(x;\theta)dx$?

Comment: $F(a)$ should be $P(X \leq a)$, yes?

Comment: @dsaxton yes...